# Caminho de referência à imagem no Label Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, orientação-a-objetos, tkinter

Estou treinando POO em um projeto pessoal que estou desenvolvendo em mostrar uma janela chamada por um botão em que mostre "amostras" de texto de um idioma, mostrando uma bandeira e um texto desse idioma. O problema é que o texto aparece, porém, a imagem que eu quero que apareça na janela não é mostrada, apesar do caminho estar correto em relação ao arquivo `main.py`. No PyCharm, quando você coloca o mouse encima de um caminho relativo à um arquivo que seja imagem corretamente ele mostra um pop-up com uma prévia da imagem. Não sei se devo fazer uma referência partindo da posição do arquivo ````main.py`ou`comandos_botao_*init*_.py```.  Ele está estruturado desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Exemplos**
`main.py`

```py
from uteis.comandos_botao import *
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from ttkthemes import ThemedStyle

root = Tk()

style_alt = ThemedStyle(root)
style_alt.set_theme('breeze')

botao = ttk.Button(root, text="Hindi", command=bt_hindi)
botao.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

**uteis\__init__.py**

```py
from tkinter import *

from uteis.textos import *


class JanelaIdioma():
    def __init__(self, idioma, texto, bandeira):
        self.idioma = idioma
        self.texto = texto
        self.bandeira = bandeira

    def criar_janela(self):
        if self.idioma == "Hindi":
            self.texto = hindi

            root_hindi = Toplevel()

            bandeira = Label(root_hindi, image=self.bandeira)
            bandeira.grid(row=0, column=0)

            letreiro_hindi = Label(root_hindi, text=self.texto, font=("Arial", 36, "bold"))
            letreiro_hindi.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

**comandos_botao\__init__.py**

```py
from uteis import *
from uteis.textos import *


def bt_hindi():
    bandeira_hindi = PhotoImage(file='img/india.png')
    janela = JanelaIdioma("hindi", hindi, bandeira_hindi).criar_janela()
```

**textos\__init__.py**

```py
hindi = "ऐसा कोई नहीं है जो खुद दर्द को प्यार करता हो, जो ऐसा करने के पीछे हो और चाहता हो, बस क्योकि यह दर्द होता है..."
```

Sei que são muitos códigos e caso estiver confuso, o projeto inteiro está no GitHub [por aqui](https://github.com/LucasRibeiroRJBR/representacoes_idioma_bandeira).

Comment: Qual o resultado para  `PhotoImage(file='../img/india.png')` e `PhotoImage(file='../../img/india.png')` ?

Comment: @PauloMarques 1- ```_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "../img/india.png": no such file or directory``` 2- ```_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "../../img/india.png": no such file or directory```. O erro completo excede o número máximo de caracteres, então coloquei na imagem [aqui](https://snipboard.io/Wn0Dvl.jpg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse parece ser o clássico problema de 'a imagem não aparece no tkinter' que ocorre quando você tenta criar uma imagem dentro de uma função. Dentro das funções suas variáveis são locais, mas quem atualiza a tela do tkinter é o `root.mainloop()` que não tem acesso à essas variáveis locais. A melhor maneira de resolver esse problema é definir suas variáveis que armazenam a imagem como uma variável de classe/objeto (estática ou dinâmica), mas se a sua função não está definida em uma classe você pode usar global para que sua variável contendo a imagem possa ser acessada pelo update do tkinter:

```
def bt_hindi():
    global bandeira_hindi
    bandeira_hindi = PhotoImage(file='img/india.png')
    janela = JanelaIdioma("hindi", hindi, bandeira_hindi).criar_janela()
```